# linked list array being different sizes

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, linked-list

heres my code:

```
using namespace std;
class Network
{
    // private function to constructe the nodes with a left and right childed
    private:

        struct node
        {


           node* left;
           node* mid;
           node* right;
           char data;
        };
        node* root;
    // public function for the the program
    public:
        char *Nodes ;
        Network()
        {
           root = NULL;
        }

        char Link(char,char);



        node* Network::Order(char* temp){


            cout << "Order:" << sizeof(temp);

            node* store; 
            store = new node[sizeof(temp)];



};
};


char Network::Link(char temp, char temp1){

};




// Smaller elements go left
// larger elements go right



/*
 * 
 */
int main() {

    Network object;
    char p[11];
    p[0] = 'a';
    p[1] = 'b';

    cout << "p:" << sizeof(p);
    object.Order(p);
    return 0;
}
```

output:  p:11 Order:4

why is order 4 it should be 11 because i passing the array p t

Comment: You should put effort into asking your question if expect people to put effort into their answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passed into a function expecting a pointer, your array is decayed into a pointer. The `sizeof` operator in the `Order` function returns the size of a pointer which is 4 bytes in your architecture.

> (C99, 6.3.2.1p3) "Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator
>   or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an
>   array, an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an
>   expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue."